# Prevent Base class properties initialization JSON.net

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to debug an issue in an asp.net core 3.1 REST API. This application has been upgraded to asp.net core 3.1 from 2.2. The asp.net core 3.1 version includes the package *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson* as it doesn't come by default. Otherwise, I don't see much difference.
The problem is that one of the endpoints shown below is working fine in 2.2 but throws an exception in 3.1.

```html
    public async Task<ActionResult<MyResponse>> ActionMethod1([FromBody] ChildClass request){
 MyResponse response = new MyResponse();//Line 2
//Some code
}
```

```html
ChildClass:Parent1{
public C_property1{get;set;}
public C_property2{get;set;}
public C_property3{get;set;}
}

Parent1:Parent2{
  public p1_property1{get;set;}
  public p1_property2{
    get{ return SomeClass.Somemethod(p1_property1)//Somemethod throws an exception
        }
  }
}
```

When I debugged the issue, I noticed that the 2.2 version doesn't try to initialize the properties of Parent1.  But the 3.1 version code tries to initialize the parent1 properties. This makes SomeClass.Somemethod() to be called which throws an exception. On the controller, the breakpoint doesn't even get to Line 2. It is not clear why this version behaves differently.

I thought it could be because of JSON.net deserializer settings. I tried adding the below on all the properties of parent1, it didn't work. Please suggest what could have changed here.

```html
       [JsonIgnore] [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Default)]
```

Comment: If you want to use NewtonsoftJson in asp.net core 3.1, I suggest you could try to add below codes like this `services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();` and install the https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson

Comment: the package is already installed and it has the line you mentioned. I need to know why the deserialization works differently.